# php ftp_connect() returns false: firewall is blocking all the ftp servers

Tags: php, ftp, firewall

ftp_connect() works only with its own ftp server (where the php code is hosted ....)
all the other connections return false .. it may be the firewall of my host server ... how to fix it ?

PHP =>

```
<?php
$ftp_connect = ftp_connect('ftp.server.com') or die('<b>FTP Connection Error ...</b>');
$login_result = ftp_login($ftp_connect, 'ftp_username','ftp_password') or die('<b>FTP Login Error ...Check Your UserName and Password</b>');
ftp_pasv($ftp_connect,true); 
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Config the firewall to open for ftp, nothing can do with your php code.

Comment: That's true, but firewall can block ftp (normally the port 21) too.

Comment: `gethostbyname()` does name resolving through your local DNS server, that has nothing to do with it.